# IIS7 - What permission to grant to which account, and where?

Tags: iis-7, permissions, file-permissions

I need my ASP page (intranet) to read files from another local Windows server.
I know that IIS7 has different system user accounts which it uses depending on the security context etc. but to be honest I don't really get it!

What I'd like to know is, what permission do I need to grant to what account, and where.
Also if possible, How :)
Ideally I really only want the minimum permission required to do this.

If it helps, the site is called with purely anonymous access as security is handled elsewhere.

Thanks, and I'd be happy to provide more info although you might need to help me get it :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, IIS refuses to serve content originating from UNC locations over plain HTTP - it requires you to use SSL and authentication.

While you can hack this by running the web page under an account that already has access to the UNC share, you should instead consider the wider security implications: this account probably has more access to the UNC content than the web page needs, so it represents a decrease in overall security.

**Start** by defining your security requirements, *then* implement them using the least possible set of permissions.

Following the reverse path does not guarantee any level of security.

Comment: The security requirement is well defined. I just need that site to be able to read files from a specific path, nothing else.